# Exercise about linearly dependency of $g$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $g$ a d-linear alternating function. Prove if $\{v_1,...,v_d\}$ is dependent, then $g(v_1,...,v_d)=0$.

I don't have a clear idea of how solve this exercise, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You almost there. Just compute $$f(v_1,\cdots,v_i,\cdots,v_n) = f(v_1,\cdots,\sum_{j=1, j\neq i} \alpha_j v_j, \cdots,v_n)$$ and then apply linearity property of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG we have $v_1 = \alpha_2 v_2 + \ldots + \alpha_d v_d$

So $f(v_1, \ldots, v_d) = \sum\limits_{i=2}^d \alpha_i f(v_i,v_2,\ldots,v_d)$

But this is 0 as $f(v_i,v_2,\ldots,v_d)=-f(v_i,v_2,\ldots,v_d)$ when we swap the 1st and ith entries.

Comment: I don't see the part of the sumatory can explain that particular part?

Comment: The sum comes from the linearity of $f$

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say that is 0? By definición of alternating?

Comment: In the final line I show if f has 2 of the same entries its 0. This shows each of the terms in the sum is 0 and hence the whole thing is the 0

Comment: @LukePeachey The OP doesn't state that $f$ is alternating, just that it's $d$-linear... There are lots of $d$-linear maps which don't have the property that they are $0$ whenever two of the arguments are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. For example, the function $g(x,y) = xy$ is a bilinear function $\mathbb{R}^1\times \mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}^1$. The vectors $1$ and $1$ are linearly dependent, but $g(1,1) = 1\neq 0$.

Maybe you meant to specify that $g$ is alternating. If so, then you can follow Luke Peachey's answer.

Comment: Yes, the function is alternating, thanks for your answer!